# A circumference as intersection of a quadric with a plane

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, quadrics

I have to prove that the following intersection, is a circumference:
$$ \mathcal{C} = \begin{cases} x^2+y^2+xy-3x-4y+z+\frac{5}{2}=0 \\ x+y+z=2 \end{cases} $$
The method I would like to use is to find the improper points, and observe that they fulfill the relationship $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$. Is this a right procedure?
For improper points:
$$ \begin{cases} x^2+y^2+xy=0 \\ z=2-x-y \\ t=0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x=(\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2})y \\ z=2-(\frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2})y \\ t=0 \end{cases}  $$
$P_{\infty} = (\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2},1,\frac{3 \mp i\sqrt{3}}{2},0)$
and $(\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+1+(\frac{3 \mp i\sqrt{3}}{2})^2$ is not zero.

Comment: The quadratic is only in variables x,y. You can use the plane equation to eliminate z by substitution into the quadratic. Now complete the square. Maybe find new coordinate system to do it in by looking at the Hessian and diagonalizing it.

Comment: We cant't work with improper points?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I don't think I have done it that way. Maybe some one else can check that for you. Or maybe if you add more details I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine, but you didn't get the points at infinity right. The correct equations are

$$ \begin{cases} x^2+y^2+xy=0 \\ z=-x-y \\ t=0 \end{cases}$$

which give

$$
P_{\infty} = 
\left(\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2},1,\frac{1 \mp i\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you, I forget to omegenize the equation of the plan.